# Java int[] arrays not transferring between methods

Tags: java, arrays

been stuck a while on this. I have the folllowing two methods:

```
public static int[] buildBoyerMooreCharTable(String pattern) {
    int[] map = new int[Character.MAX_VALUE + 1];
    char[] ca = pattern.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++)
    {
            for (int k = 0; k < ca.length; k++)
            {
                if (Character.getNumericValue(ca[k]) == i)
                {
                    //System.out.println("YO");
                    map[i] = findMax(1, pattern.length() - pattern.lastIndexOf(ca[k]) - 1);
                }
            }
    }
    for (int j =0 ; j < ca.length; j++)
    { System.out.println(map[Character.getNumericValue(ca[j])]);}
    System.out.println("Gut check " + map[Character.getNumericValue('a')]);

    return map;
}
```

Method 2 (only relevant code shown)

```
public static List<Integer> boyerMoore(String pattern, String text) {
    int i = pattern.length() - 1;
    int j = pattern.length() - 1;
    int k = 0;
    boolean yo = false;
    ArrayList<Integer> ans = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int[] last_table = buildBoyerMooreCharTable(pattern);

    System.out.println("Did it transfer " + last_table[Character.getNumericValue('b')]);
...
```

The problem is, I believe, in my line:

```
        int[] last_table = buildBoyerMooreCharTable(pattern);
```

The table is not transferring right! In my display window I am getting the following:

```
Gut check 3 
Gut check 0
Did it transfer 0
```

Gut check 3 is correct! All the rest...no.

This is with it being called as

```
StringSearch ss = new StringSearch();
String yay = "abcdabcdabce";
StringSearch.buildBoyerMooreCharTable(yay);
List<Integer> a_i = new ArrayList<Integer>();
a_i = StringSearch.boyerMoore("d", yay);
```

So...when the method boyerMoore is actually called... we are getting a failed value.

Circumventing all the code I've posted - I think there may be a matter of not understanding how to set arrays equal to each other going on...

Comment: What you're doing looks good. You are however comparing `map[Character.getNumericValue('a')]` to `map[Character.getNumericValue('b')]` - could that be the problem?

Comment: What are you expecting `Character#getNumericValue()` to return?

Comment: Show the result of your println statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling Character.getNumericValue(char) but this doesn't appear to be a good choice here.  For the range of this function returns is -1 to value greater than 1000. e.g. Character.getNumericValue('?') is -1.

I suspect you want to use the ASCII value which is what the value already is, so you don't need to call any function to do this.

```
    if (Character.getNumericValue(ca[k]) == i)
```

should be just

```
    if (ca[k] == i)
```

Searching every possible character is pretty inefficient given you know only a limit set will every appear.  I suggest you just search for the characters actually present.

---

For your interest the following code prints amoungst other things

```
for (int i = 0; i <= Character.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
    int value = Character.getNumericValue(i);
    if (value >= 0)
        System.out.println((char) i + " is " + value);
}
```

For Roman numeric characters

```
ⅰ is 1
ⅱ is 2
ⅲ is 3
ⅳ is 4
ⅴ is 5
ⅵ is 6
ⅶ is 7
ⅷ is 8
ⅸ is 9
ⅹ is 10
ⅺ is 11
ⅻ is 12
ⅼ is 50
ⅽ is 100
ⅾ is 500
ⅿ is 1000
```